How to record screen with FFmpeg in macOS without getting this error: "Selected framerate is not supported by the device."
I'm trying to record the screen using FFmpeg on macOS.
First I run this command:
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ''

The output is:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x12ff058a0] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x12ff058a0] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x12ff058a0] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x12ff058a0] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x12ff058a0] [0] MacBook Pro Microphone

Then I run this command:
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i 0:0 -fps_mode passthrough output.mp4

And there is an error:
[avfoundation @ 0x150705610] Selected framerate (29.970030) is not supported by the device.
[avfoundation @ 0x150705610] Supported modes:
[avfoundation @ 0x150705610]   1920x1080@[15.000000 30.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x150705610]   1280x720@[15.000000 30.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x150705610]   1080x1920@[15.000000 30.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x150705610]   1760x1328@[15.000000 30.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x150705610]   640x480@[15.000000 30.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x150705610]   1328x1760@[15.000000 30.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x150705610]   1552x1552@[15.000000 30.000000]fps

Removing -fps_mode passthrough didn't help.
How to fix it?

Start your command like this:
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i 0:0

